# how to find the value is not in mongodb, value is coming from constant array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array like this

```
let arr = [a,b,c]
```

and a collection like this

```
{val:a},{val:b}
```

I want to know that document with val=c is not in the collection.

Comment: You actually want to know that `{val:a},{val:b}` is in the collection and `{val: c}` is not in the collection, right?

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: null, vals: {$addToSet: "$val"}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, notIncluded: {$setDifference: [arr, "$vals"]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OLpI24j7o5g)

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter, and a findOne for each value like:

```
let arr = ["a","b","c"];
let notfound = arr.filter((value) => db.collection.findOne({val:value}) === null)
```

Or you could use distinct with a filter:

```
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
let existing = db.collection.distinct("val")
let notfound = arr.filter((value)=> existing.indexOf(value) == -1)
```